# Razor adding a white space before content

Tags: razor

I am outputting an address that I would like to comma separate.
If I don't include any html before outputting the address it is shown correctly without any additional spaces.

**Example:**

97 Glen Road, Holywood, BT18 0LE

**Currently Getting:**

97 Glen Road , Holywood , BT18 0LE

My code is:

```
    <p class="no-margin-top">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address1)
    @if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Address2)){
        @:, @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address2)
    }
    @if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Address3)){
        @:, @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address3)
    }
    @if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Town)){
        @:, @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Town)
    }
    @if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.County)){
        @(", ")@("Co. ")@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.County)
    }
    @if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Postcode)){
        @(", ")@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Postcode)
    }
    @if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Country)){
        @(", ")@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Country)
    }
```

I have tried outputting the comma differently as shown above but still getting the same result.

I have also tried removing all spaces from the code as well as using @Html.Raw.

Would appreciate it if anyone has a fix for this or could suggest a better way of doing it.

**UPDATE**

Due to changes within the Framework Darin's solution will now produce errors.

You will need to ensure you are using System.Linq

Then amended Darin's code as follows:

```
    public string FormattedAddress
    {
        get
        {
            var values = new[] { Address1, Address2, Address3, Town, Postcode, "Co. " + County }.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x));
            return string.Join(", ", values);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WOW, this looks like a terrible mess you've ended up in your view. I would recommend you to use a view model and add the following property to your view model that will take care of properly formatting the address:

```
public string FormattedAddress
{
    get
    {
        var values = new[] { Address1, Address2, Address3, Town, Postcode, "Co. " + County }
            .Where(!string.IsNullOrEmpty);
        return string.Join(", ", values);
    }
}
```

and then in your view replace the mess with:

```
<p class="no-margin-top">
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FormattedAddress)
</p>
```

and if now you tell me that you have violated all good practices and are not using view models, but are passing directly your domain entities to the view, well, other than telling you that this is wrong you could somehow hack it in the view:

```
<p class="no-margin-top">
    @{
        var values = new[] { item.Address1, item.Address2, item.Address3, item.Town, item.Postcode, "Co. " + item.County }
            .Where(!string.IsNullOrEmpty);
        var formattedAddress = string.Join(", ", values);
    }
    @formattedAddress
</p>
```

But honestly go use a view model.

Comment: Had to amend the view model code slightly as I was getting numerous errors. But thanks Darin for pointing me in the right direction. I had a little extra help from http://stackoverflow.com/a/11844234/1472203

Comment: Yeah, I forgot an `=` sign in the Razor view. Also I guess that you should use `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FormattedAddress)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try forcing the comma plus space to be text using a razor text markup. It may be a razor interpretation problem.

```
{<text>, </text>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address2)}
```

Good luck

Comment: This produces the same problem.

Comment: @Stephen Solution above looks so much better anyway - please ignore this/